# VBA Connection Issue with MySQL - Connected at Top of Macro, but not bottom

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

I have a macro that opens an ADODB connection to a MySQL library.  There are two queries that are generated in the macro.  The first, which works, is a select statement to check for duplicates.  The second, which is not working, is to insert records onto the same table the select statement referenced.  I am receiving no errors from VBA, and when I copy/paste directly into MySQL the query works fine.

At the top of my macro I set up the connection as follows:

```vb
   TimesheetConn = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=*server number*;PORT=*port number*;database=my_db;UID=User;PWD=password;Option=2"

   'Connection Info
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   On Error GoTo AdoError
       Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
      With cnn
    .ConnectionString = TimesheetConn
    .Open
    .CommandTimeout = 0
      End With
   Set FIT_Data = New ADODB.Recordset
   Set Task_Data = New ADODB.Recordset
```

I then develop the Select query (fitidquery) and run it as:

```vb
   FIT_Data.Open fitidquery, cnn, CursorType = 2
```

I do not close the connection, but then move on to generate my next query, an insert query (addtasks3), by looping through rows and assigning variables.

Then I try to call the connection again with:

```vb
   Task_Data.Open addtasks3, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
   cnn.Close
```

And it doesn't work, nor does it give me any errors either for VBA or SQL.  As said before, copying the result of debug.print(addtasks3) into MySQL the query runs correctly and inserts the records.

I've tried opening a 2nd connection with the same parameters.  That didn't work as well.  I moved the On Error language down to in front of the second query call and it moves on to the AdoError message which seems to indicate that the connection is lost there.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Try to add `ReadOnly=False;` to you connection string -  [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971903/vba-ado-update-query)

Comment: I added ReadOnly=False to the connection string, no change.

Comment: Can you remove the on Error and copy here there you got?

Comment: I agree with Adirmola, when you use any *On Error ...* when debugging you're saying "If there is an error, just ignore it". Not a proper way to debug malfunctioning code.

Comment: I removed on error, I didn't have it originally, I only put it in to see if I could figure out where it was breaking.  It still does not write the rows to my db table but no error message is given.

Answer (score 1):

If you issue an `Insert`-statement, there is no need to involve a recordset. You can simply execute

```vb
 cnn.Execute addtasks3
```

Or, if you want to get the number of rows you inserted, use a `ADODB.Command`:

```vb
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = addtasks3
Dim rowsInserted As Long
Call cmd.Execute(rowsInserted)
Debug.Print rowsInserted & " rows inserted."
```

Comment: I changed to the execute statement; it looks like the connection is still failing as the records did not appear on the db table.  No error messages were given though.

Comment: Have you added the `Debug.Print`-Statement? What does it show?  Have you used the debugger to step thru the code? Have you removed the `On error` statement?

Comment: I've used debug.print for printing the query variables to see if it was an issue in the SQL code itself, when run through MySQL they had no issues.  I've used the debugger to step through everything, it behaves as if it is working.  On error statement has been removed (and wasn't there originally when I started trying to figure out what was happening).  It's like it's randomly losing the connection before the second query, but not giving an error for it.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I read your question wrong.  The debug.print for rows inserted returns "0 rows inserted".  There should be 1.

Comment: I would say the `Insert` was executed sucessfully, but didn't insert any row. Hard to tell why not, but (except for the case of using `On Error Resume Next`) if the `sql`-statement itself had an error, it would throw an error message in VBA.

Comment: Is there a chance my table is locked from the select statement previous?  I would think it would give me an error message if so.  I feel like an error is definitely there (as evidenced by the on error sending me to the error message I had plugged in when I had that language in there).

Comment: If you have no `On Error`-statement and the `Insert`-statement fails, you would get a runtime error at that statement (for example, I just provoked a `Unique Constraint error`). ADO shows the error message issued by the database. If there was a lock, the insert-statement would `hang`.

Comment: I didn't even think about a on error resume next I had in my code as I thought it only applied to that section (VBA newbie).  It clicked in my head after you mentioned it though and I figured it out.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @M.R. also note that `Call` is always redundant (it's an obsolete keyword, like `Global` and `While...Wend` - just drop the parentheses), and `Dim ... As New...` creates an auto-instantiated object, which should probably be avoided since that makes an object for which you can't destroy the reference (it gets re-created automatically)

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon: I prefer to use `Call` because it keeps the syntax similar to the call of a function (`Workbook.Open`, anyone?) - and it prevents me to accidentally use the infamous ByRef  to ByVal  conversion. For the `...As New...`: I would assume that the object is destroyed at the end of the function - isn't it? At least the `VarPtr` shows the same memory address when I call a sub several times.

Comment: You do your think - I'd argue that it's *precisely* because it *looks* like a function call that it's harmful, and it's usually very inconsistently used (e.g. I've yet to see `Call MsgBox`), but eh ;-)  ..as for the reference, yes, it's destroyed - but since many folks tend to _also_ do `Set thing = Nothing`, it needs to be said that nulling an auto-instantiated reference can't be verified, because `If thing Is Nothing Then` will always return `False`. This can (has) cause(d) very subtle and very frustrating bugs.

Comment: Why should it be harmfull to let it look like a function call? No matter if I call a Sub or a Function using `Call` - it shows that I don't care about the result value (if any). If I later change my mind, I just change the call to an assignment - and if by accident I would do this for a Sub, the compiler will tell me immedialty. But I am misusing the comment section for a discussion (and high time for "Feierabend")

Comment: I've admittedly never seen Call before today so I will be doing some research so I can understand fully what the two of you are talking about. :-)  I came into this job with very little vba experience (just altering a few variables kind of stuff) and have been put more or less as lead on developing some automated tools with it so I'm kind of crash-coursing as I go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I have to say thank you to all of you that mentioned On Errors.  Your descriptions after rereading finally made it click with me what I did.  I had thought that On Error Resume Next only worked for the line it was in front of in the code (I am still very much a VBA newbie learning as I go) and didn't realize that it would follow through the rest of the code.  I had one before my first query because if its a new row it wouldn't return anything to check a duplicate against and cause an error. Hence why I wasn't getting error messages.

I added "On Error GoTo 0" after that section and now I'm getting error messages again.  Turns out my user is denied use of the Insert Command for that table (even though I modeled it after a table where it does have use), so it looks like I just need to figure that out.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is almost the worst thing on the internet.

Comment: Now that I know what it actually does (and not just what I thought it did) I completely agree!